# How can I change a Ubuntu Desktop installation, to a shell login (with startX when I want to go graphical)?

Tags: command-line, login, gui, root

I have a  working Ubuntu Desktop 20.04 installation, but there are some things I need to do as root and I need to do them before the X session starts. I needed the help of the Desktop install, to get X right, but now that it's right I'd be happier with a command line login (so long as I can start X, like 'startX'). Though I'd also like to be able to get back out, whence I came, in the end and the canned GUI seems to have a Hotel California ending....

Now I have two problems in this. One is, the setup just gives a GUI login and no way I can see to "exit to shell, su, startX". Other is, although I've given 'root' a password I cannot log in -as- root, to the X session through the login box. Which might obviate the need to log in to shell as root. But still I want the authority.

All I've turned up is people saying you shouldn't do it unless you can figure out how, for yourself. Not useful.

Comment: Thanks. I do not see the behavior described in the link. Ctrl-Alt-F1 does not give a console, virtual or otherwise - it spawns another GUI login screen. And after that, Ctrl-Alt-F2 gives me the original completed login screen, but dimmed out and no response to mouse or keyboard. What I am after, is an escape from the GUI environment entirely (no "virtual console, the "real" console).

Comment: I found this in another thread, says ctrl-alt-F1 has been repurposed to another login (GUI) screen:   

"The actual used tty consoles have changed around with the introduction of Wayland and 17.10. Now tty1 always contains the login screen, and tty2 contains your actual loaded session.

So use Ctrl+Alt+F3 up to Ctrl+Alt+F7 for getting to an actual unused tty and use Ctrl+Alt+F2 to go back to GUI."                                  

Ctrl-Alt-F3 gives me what I want, a plain terminal session login and it allows my root login, so consider this solved.

Answer (score 3):

It is a systemd setting that decides to act as a "server":

```
systemctl set-default multi-user.target
```

or as a "desktop":

```
sudo systemctl set-default graphical.target
```